# Can I set a browser favicon in .php file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have seen similar questions on this site, but all of them were dealing with different languages.

I have a website I am designing in Wordpress, and I want to set a favicon for it. If I have the desired icon in a designated location on the site, can I set the favicon with PHP alone, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

echo this in the `<head></head>` section:

```
echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />';
```

#### For Wordpress

Add this line: `<link rel="icon" href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">` into `header.php` from your template

Answer (score 4):

You dont have to use php:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/favicon.png"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

yes you can. just embed you html in that php file:

```
echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico?v=038622610830">
';
```

Note: this line should be applied into `<head></head>` elements block to get work it.

Answer (score 1):

**Using only PHP - not, you can't.**

You have to use `echo` command for  HTML tags in webpage's `<head>` section, which are showing a favicon. That's all.

```
<?php
//...
echo '<link rel="shortcut icon" href="URL TO FAVICON"/>';
//...
?>
```

Please read also: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Favicon